# Exception: Protocol error: Unknown transport

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, signalr

I installed SignalR using nuget and created a very basic hub.
Then I registered my hubs in global.asax. But I get this exception when I navigate to the url of my hub.
I use ASP.NET MVC 2 and Telerik MVC Extensions.

This is my Global.asax

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("elmah.axd");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("favicon.ico");
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );

    }

    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RouteTable.Routes.MapHubs("~/flatwhitehubs");
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        //RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);           
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

        Application[ApplicationRepository.Current.StockLockObject] = new object();
        Application["InvoiceGeneratorLock"] = new object();
    }
```

and this is my hub:

```
[HubName("FlatwhiteHub")]
public class FlatwhiteHub : Hub, IConnected, IDisconnect
{
    public Task JoinGroup(string groupName)
    {
        return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
    }

    public Task Connect()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task Reconnect(IEnumerable<string> groups)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public Task Disconnect()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```